# VBScript function is taking out foreign characters

Tags: vbscript

I have an old function in VBScript for Classic ASP that strips out illegal characters when a form is submitted, but it's also stripping out foreign characters and replacing them with junk like A*@L, etc.

The function looks like this:

```
Private Function stripillegal(fieldcontents)
    if isnull(fieldcontents) then
        stripillegal = ""
    else
        Dim stripped, stripillegal_c, stripillegal_i
        stripped = ""

        if isempty(fieldcontents) then fieldcontents = ""

        fieldcontents = CStr( fieldcontents )
        fieldcontents = Trim( fieldcontents )

        if Len(fieldcontents)>0 then
            for stripillegal_i = 1 to Len(fieldcontents)
                stripillegal_c = asc(mid(fieldcontents, stripillegal_i, 1))

                select case stripillegal_c
                case 39
                    stripped = stripped & "&#39;"
                case 37
                    stripped = stripped & "&#37;"
                case 34 ' quote (34)
                    stripped = stripped & "&#34;"
                case else
                    stripped = stripped & chr(stripillegal_c)
                end select
                ' response.write stripped & "<br>"
            next
        end if

        stripped = trim(stripped)
        while Right(stripped, 1) = chr(13) OR Right(stripped, 1) = chr(10)
            stripped = left(stripped, len(stripped)-1)
        wend

        stripillegal = stripped
    end if
End Function
```

I'm wondering how to tell it to allow foreign characters like those found in French or Spanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Regular Expressions](http://www.code-tips.com/2009/04/vbscript-string-clean-function-remove.html) can clean these strings up nicely while avoiding foreign characters.

More specificly, this function:

```
Function strClean (strtoclean)
    Dim objRegExp, outputStr
    Set objRegExp = New Regexp

    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.Pattern = "[(?*"",\\<>&#~%{}+_.@:\/!;]+"
    outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(strtoclean, "-")

    objRegExp.Pattern = "\-+"
    outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(outputStr, "-")

    strClean = outputStr
End Function
```